# Kinesis: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to describe a kinesis stream and I keep getting the following error:

`{u'message': u"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.\n\nThe Canonical String for this request should have been\n'POST\n/\n\nhost:kinesis.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\nx-amz-date:20170206T213923Z\nx-amz-target:Kinesis_20131202.DescribeStream\n\nhost;x-amz-date;x-amz-target\ne44afc66cc6ee6f40d4f09cc4f15e8d85bff345f0a8736062433576fdc427db9'\n\nThe String-to-Sign should have been\n'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20170206T213923Z\n20170206/us-east-1/kinesis/aws4_request\n7fb3a26fed309c6a6f7667a6abe2224ed132878a79d4aac984bc3b19b3add7c7'\n", u'__type': u'InvalidSignatureException'}`

I know my boto keys are setup properly:

```
>>> import boto
>>> boto.set_stream_logger('boto')
>>> s3 = boto.connect_s3()
2017-02-06 16:46:47,366 boto [DEBUG]:Using access key found in config file.
2017-02-06 16:46:47,366 boto [DEBUG]:Using secret key found in config file.
```

Thanks

Comment: Copy/paste error in the config file of the secret?  Or, less likely, the access key id?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by regenerated my secret id and key. Must have gotten truncated on the copy or something.